# HTML to DOCX Plugin?

Tags: module, plugin

Is there an HTML to DOCX plugin/module for Expression Engine? I am looking for a solution akin to [Shine PDF](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/shine-pdf).

We would like to allow users to download PDF or Word doc versions of their content. The reason for a DOCX format is to allow users to edit the content after they have downloaded it.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Ehhh, I've made my own to do both pdf and and excel files. Don't know about docx, probably gonna have to roll your own.

Comment: Hmmm...OK. That stinks. Thanks. I did find [PHPWord](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord). Maybe that will work.

Comment: Yeah, that's a pretty stable release library. I wrote modules that generated PDFs and Excel files using TCPDF and PHPExcel. It really wasn't hard just took some time to learn the libraries.